# How to enable Xdebug on local Macbook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

Need Xdebug extension enabled in my local development environment.

- PHP Version: PHP 8.0.10 (CLI)
- OS: Mac ( Chip Apple M1 )

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize the steps that worked for me always.

1. Reconfirm x-debug installation on the local work desk or enabled in php.ini by running the following command:
   ➜  ~ `PHP -v`
2. Run the below command to install x-debug:
   On Apple M1 hardware, you might instead need to use:
   ➜  ~ `arch -arm64 sudo pecl install xdebug`

If you have different architecture, below might be suitable.
➜  ~ `arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug`

Note: I had installed PHP using Homebrew before like :
➜  ~ `brew install php`

3. Now, with above #2, X-debug should be installed and enabled in php.ini.
   You might get something similar as below:

   **Build process completed successfully
   Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.10/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so'
   install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-3.0.4
   Extension xdebug enabled in php.ini**

Tips:
**Usecase 1: Xdebug installed but not enabled in php.ini.**

Steps:>

(a) Read the PHP ini file loaded, active with below.
➜  ~ `PHP --ini`

(b) Use vi editor and add the following line to php.ini: `zend_extension="xdebug.so"`
( Note: You may also provide the path instead of just xdebug.so. For example, my local machine path is something like this:- */opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.10/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so*

(c) Save and exit editor and try `php -v` again to confirm x-debug enabled.

**Usecase 2: You had run pecl command with the wrong architecture mentioned.**

(a) Uninstall x-Debug with below command:
➜  ~ `sudo pecl uninstall xdebug`

(b) Re-run install command as shared in Step 2 above with caution using correct architecture.

Comment: If `arch -arm64 sudo pecl install xdebug` gives you "Bad CPU type in executable" error, try `arch -arm64e sudo pecl install xdebug`.